# AngularJS for Highcharts with dynamic ajax data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts, highcharts-ng

I'm learning Javascript and AngularJS by integrating two examples: [Spring MVC and AngularJS](https://github.com/robharrop/spring-angularjs) and [AngularJS and Highcharts](http://jsfiddle.net/pablojim/46rhz/).

This seemingly simple task has puzzled me for a few days:
In the Spring REST-powered backend, I added the class Book with a property "prices", an array of doubles to represent the monthly or yearly prices of the book. The AngularJS client shows the "prices" by adding the following code to html:

```
<div style="height:300px;width:250px;overflow:auto;float:left;">
    <table class="table table-striped">
       <tr ng-repeat="price in book.prices">
          <td>{{price}}</td>
       </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

and the following code to the controller:

```
 var bookId = $routeParams.bookId;
 if (bookId === 'new') {
    $scope.book = new Book();
 } else {
    $scope.book = Book.get({bookId: bookId});
 }
```

The table updates dynamically with the data from the backend. Pretty neat and elegant!

What baffles me is the highcharts part. I added the following to the html:

```
<div style="border: 1px solid #ccc; width: 620px; float: right">
     <highchart id="chart1" config="chartConfig"></highchart>
</div>
```

and some static values for the "prices" to the controller:

```
var prices = [60.5, 55.7]; // Static data works

$scope.chartConfig = {
    options : {
        chart : {
            type : 'line'
        }
    },
    series : [ {
        data : prices 
    } ],
    title : {
        text : 'Monthly Book Prices'
    },

    loading : false
}
```

And the hichcharts works fine with AngularJS.

I then tried to update the dynamic "prices" from the backend to the chart by adding some code to the controller:

```
// var prices = [60.5, 55.7]; // Static data works
var prices = $scope.book.prices
```

or

```
// var prices = [60.5, 55.7]; // Static data works
var prices  = [$scope.book.prices]
```

and after some time realized this was a quite naive understanding of AngularJS. I've also followed the way described in

[How to produce a highchart (using angular js) with json data coming from an Ajax request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17451941/how-to-produce-a-highchart-using-angular-js-with-json-data-coming-from-an-ajax) without success.

Is there an elegant way like the prices table shown above for the Highcharts to display the dynamic data from backend?

Comment: Don't you just need to reload the chart after having loaded the data?

Comment: See the first example [link](https://github.com/robharrop/spring-angularjs). The chart is supposed to be reloaded after pushing a button on UI (such as book detail).

Answer (score 3):

Try changing the data in your chart config directly:

```
$scope.chartConfig.series[0].data = $scope.book.prices
```

Or use an object for the series:

```
var prices = {data: [60.5, 55.7]}; // Static data works

$scope.chartConfig = {
    options : {
        chart : {
            type : 'line'
        }
    },
    series : [ prices ],
    title : {
        text : 'Monthly Book Prices'
    },

    loading : false
}
```

Then later:

```
prices.data = [60.5, 55.7]
```